# Flickr photo ID lifetime

Tags: flickr

Does anybody have more details on the lifetime of flickr photo IDs?

E.g. I do a search using http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

which returns a list of photos and their IDs.

Does the ID ever get invalid? Probably when the image is removed. But could there be other reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't have thought there'd be any reason for them to change the photo id. It's used by a lot of people for a lot of different uses - it would cause massive headaches for everyone including Flickr if they ever did.

Comment: I very much agree. I just can't find any documentation on it.